# Flutter: increase appBar icon height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to put an icon instead of the title for `appBar` widget but I can't set proper height of this icon.

[image]

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(220.0),
  child: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/mobile-phone.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 120,
          height: 120,
        )
      ],
    ),
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  ),
),
```

The icon reaches it's maximum size about 60 (units?) despite that I set the height much more bigger and it's actual size is bigger also.

How to force height setup for the icon in `appBar` widget?

Comment: I can see that the appbar height is getting affected by this. Can you do this and tell me whether it is working fine or not. Despite of using `BoxFit.contain`, use `BoxFit.cover` or `BoxFit.fill` or `BoxFit.fitHeight`. I guess this should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer but none of these props work.

Comment: Okay, then we will have to see into the details.

Comment: I suppose that I should increase title font size in this case but can't find how to set font size for the appBar's title unfortunately.

Comment: I can tell you how to increase the appbar's title font size, it is easy. See the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should looks like this

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(220.0),
  child: AppBar(
    flexibleSpace: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/mobile-phone.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 120,
          height: 120,
        )
      ],
    ),
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Don't you know how to make appBar height flexible depending on it's child height?